# Output Table on While Loop using Dompdf

Tags: php, html, mysql, dompdf

How to print a table on while loop to get data from database using Dompdf?

Below are my codes that I have done but with fail result.

```
$html =  '<table>
<tr>
  <td>Date</td><td>Name</td>
</tr>';

// Query from mysql 
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $date = $row['date '];
   $name = $row['name'];

   $html . = '<tr>
    <td> ' . $date . ' </td>' . $name . '</td>
   </tr>';
  }
}

$html .= '</table>';

require('../dompdf/autoload.inc.php');
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->load_html($html);

$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("Result.pdf",array("Attachment"=>0));
$dompdf->clear();
```

Comment: now you went and edited without marking it as an edit, stating that you made a mistake.

Comment: sorry @Fred-ii- but how do mark it as an edit? I did mention on the update   that I'am making a correction on the codes

Comment: *"Stack tip"*: Whenever you make a mistake, you need to specify in your (edited) question that you changed your code to what should have been the proper syntax. This is mostly because, when people post answers based on what you (originally) posted, others will look at the answer(s) with the proper syntax and compare it with what you now have, and may tell themselves: *"They have the right syntax, so why the answer(s)?"* And they might downvote the answer(s) because of this. So, always put your "new" code below your original question, with **"Edit:**, and a quick explanation ;-)

Answer (score 2):

<strike>**1** The string must be quoted.  Change</strike>

```
$html .= </table>
```

to

```
$html .= '</table>';
```

**2** The operator ".=" must not have a space in it.  Change

```
$html . = '<tr>
```

to

```
$html .= '<tr>
```

**3** Finally, there is probably not a space in the "date", so Change

```
$date = $row['date '];
```

to

```
$date = $row['date'];
```

Comment: thanks for the help @Webjuju. After I made the corrections, I have this error `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded`

Comment: just before your **require()** call, can you **die($html);** to be sure that the html portion is not the culprit.  how many rows do you have?

Comment: If I add the `die($html);`, the result works great. I have around 400 rows.

Comment: well, put a **die(__LINE__)** after each line until you find the issue.  may i also recommend http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found that the solution is I need to extend the `max_execution_time`. Just want to know if there is any issue if I extend the time. Maybe like performance or that is not the good solution?

Comment: sometimes these things just take time based on the power of the server generating the pdf.  as they say, *"mileage may vary"*